# Derivative of a Rational function $f(x)=\sqrt{2x-5\over3x+1}$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I'm trying to find the derivative of,

$$f(x)=\sqrt{2x-5\over3x+1}$$

I think I can change this into

$$f(x)= \left({2x-5 \over 3x+1}\right)^{1\over2}
\\ =[(2x-5)(3x+1)^{-1}]^{1 \over 2}$$

Am I not right??

From now, how do I continue??

Comment: Use one more property of the exponentials and apply Leibniz' rule for differentiating a product.

Comment: I feel the need to point out that $f$ is not a rational function.  Rational functions have the form $P(x)/Q(x)$ where $P,Q$ are polynomials.  So, the function is not rational because of the radical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have right, from here you have to use this formula: $(u^n)'=n\cdot u^{n-1}\cdot u'$, where $u=(2x-5)(3x+1)^{-1}\Rightarrow u'=\frac{17}{(3x+1)^2}$

> So you'll obtain: $\frac{1}{2} \cdot u^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot u'=\frac{1}{2}\cdot (2x-5)^{-\frac{1}{2}}(3x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\frac{17}{(3x+1)^2}=\frac{17}{2\sqrt{2x-5}(3x+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

Answer (score 5):

this is better done with logarithmic differentiation. here is how it works. we have $$y =\sqrt{\frac{2x-5}{3x+1}}\to \ln y = \frac12\left(\ln(2x-5) - \ln(3x+1)\right) $$  differencing the las equation we get
$$\frac{2}{y}\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2}{2x-5} - \frac{3}{3x+1 } = \frac{17}{(2x-5)(3x+1)}$$ you can simplify more if it is needed.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=[(2x-5)(3x+1)^{-1}]^{1 \over 2}$$

So,
$$\begin{align}
f'(x) & =\frac12\left(\frac{2x-5}{3x+1}\right)^{-1/2}\frac{(3x+1)2-(2x-5)3}{(3x+1)^2},\quad\text{chain and quotient rules}\\
& = \frac12\left(\frac{2x-5}{3x+1}\right)^{-1/2}\frac{17}{(3x+1)^2}.
\end{align}$$

This simplifies to Lucas' answer.

Comment: The 1/2 factor just forgot to bring itself to next line and then yeah you will have the Lucas answer thingy. :p

Comment: Yep, I'll fix it.